# Play Framework - Set URL for Assets

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In production, I want to use nginx for serving statics. How to set a URL for assets in Play framework that we can use in both development and production. I like the way Django set `STATIC_URL` in settings.

EDIT:

In Django, you can set `STATIC_URL = 'https://static.domain.com/'` in `settings.py`. In templates, you can call the value for:

```
<script src='{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js'></script>
```

Comment: Write more, not everybody knows what does `STATIC_URL` ind Django do.

Comment: @biesior I've just added the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add anything you need to the application.conf, so for an instance it can be the static domain (other than current app's domain), next you can ie. write simple getter in your controller (Java version):

**application.conf**

```
staticUrl = "https://static.domain.com/"
```

controller **Application.java**

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static final String STATIC_URL = Play.application().configuration().getString("staticUrl", "http://localhost:9000");
    public static String getStaticUrl(String path){
        return STATIC_URL + path;
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

**view**:

```html
<script src='@Application.getStaticUrl("js/your_script.js")'></script>
<!-- or just -->
<script src='@(Application.STATIC_URL)js/your_script.js'></script>
```

### By the way...

If you just need to use absolute url pointing to the current domain, you can do it directly in the view using `Assets.at` function with `absoluteURL()` ie:

```html
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("js/your_script.js").absoluteURL()'></script> 
<!-- or for https version -->
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("js/your_script.js").absoluteURL(true)'></script>
```