# play framework 2.2.x .How do i override Assets.at() method

Tags: playframework-2.0

My play app at localhost.
but my assets at "http://my.assets.com",
i want to change controllers.Assets.at() to redirect("http://my.assets.com/"+filename);

but i can't override controllers.Assets,Is there any way to solve this problem

Looks like this:

```
public class Assets{
    public static Result at(String filename){
         return redirect("http://my.assets.com/"+filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20322226/830153).

Comment: No,My app has been complete, Now, I want to have the app and separation of assets on a different server

Answer (score 0):

Why do you absolutely  want to override an existing method? Simply create another controller :

```
object MyAssets extends Controller {
    def at(file:String) = {
    ...
    }
}
```

And add the route to the routes file :

```
/*     controllers.MyAssets.at(file:String)
```

Comment: 1.@SeanSnow code is java, your code is scala.
2.by setup your own controller for assets, you lost some framework feature for public assets, like etag